# new tab ID in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know the ID which the **original** new tab page of chrome would take when I open a new tab?
to inject a javascript code into it.

 ** note that the new tab I'm talking about here is the original chrome new tab page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, JavaScript injection into Chrome's original New Tab Page is not allowed for security reasons.